# PHP string not working well outside 'for' statement

Tags: php, arrays, string, wordpress, for-loop

We've done a Wordpress searchform and we don't manage to make a PHP string working well outside a `for` statement.

We're using a WordPress Query to make the filter work. As you'll see, we've been using different custom fields.

The rest of strings such as `$height` and `$tshirt_size-` are defined hundreds of lines below and work perfectly.

The only problem we've got is that we cannot make the `$all_dates` string work outside the `for` statement.

When we try to print it inside works fine and shows all the dates we are requesting. But when we try to do it outside, only shows one date (the last one).

That is how the query works (I hope the annotations are clear enough):

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;   

query_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'bbdd',
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_query' => array(
            $tshirt_size,           /*WORKS WELL*/
            $shoe_size,              /*WORKS WELL*/
            $height,                 /*WORKS WELL*/
            $weight,                 /*WORKS WELL*/
            array( 'key' => 'age',
                   'value' => array($all_dates) /*NOT WORKING*/ ),)) );

$date_from = $_GET["date_from"]; 
$date_from = strtotime($date_from); 

$date_to = $_GET["date_to"]; 
$date_to = strtotime($date_to);

for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400)
{
    $all_dates = "'" . date("d/m/Y", $i) . "', ";

echo $all_dates; /*PRINTING ALL DATES*/ 
}  
echo $all_dates; /*PRINTING ONLY ONE DATE (LAST DATE)*/ ?>
```

Comment: Concatenation... read about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400)
{
    $all_dates .= "'" . date("d/m/Y", $i) . "',  ";

}  
echo $all_dates; /*PRINTING ALL DATES*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot. We've just learn about concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

it is normal, in your "for", you print a date each time you cycle, outside the "for" you print only the last date, to print ALL your dates you have to concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

Your not concatenating the original $all_dates:

$all_dates **.**= "'" . date("d/m/Y", $i) . "', ";